# Undeleting comments breaks the layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools, undelete

As the title says, a mod undeleting a comment adds a second top bar, adds a random second copy of the logo and top buttons in the middle of the page, pushes the comments to the bottom of the page, and adds some other graphical issues.

This occurs on both scifi and outdoors.

A picture says a thousand words:

[image: Top of messed-up page]

[image: Bottom of messed-up page]

Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
macOS Sierra/10.12.6

Comment: Just tried it on Arqade, and I see the same thing. (Chrome on Windows)

Comment: ---Let me test this.--- Oh yeah. That's weird.

Comment: Wow. That's... amazing. A set of extensive page layout (in the ASP.NET Razor sense) changes went out a couple days back. My money's on that off-hand over the top bar redesign, but I'll ask around either way. :)

Comment: I reproduce similar breakage when undeleting a comment on Stack Overflow. I did not see it yesterday, so I doubt the changes @Adam is thinking of are related if those "went out a couple days back".

Comment: @CodyGray I misremembered - the change set I was thinking of went in on Friday, but it was only built to production late Monday UTC. I guess my memory just split the difference and settled on "a couple of days".

Comment: I could swear the same thing happened on SU some time back. I run a unsupported browser though... ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek nah, such break isn't any browser fault, it's the server sending whole document instead of just HTML chunk in some AJAX response.

Comment: This happened to me yesterday on Mi Yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix is live now. My late-night theory was right - a spot got missed during `Layout` refactoring. :)