# User profile does not open while directly clicking a name in comment from Stack Exchange mobile app

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-app

I can't open a commenter profile while directly click the commenter name in comment from mobile app

You can check it my below comment... You can't see my profile while directly click my name in the mobile app. But I can go to with long press and go to three dot button. Bla bla bla... Simply I thought it's not user-friendly. It's my suggestion..! Kindly take any action :)

Comment: What app? iOS or android? Stack Overflow app, or Stack Exchange app?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's StackExchange. See title.It was originally asked in MSO and OP confirmed stackexchange app

Comment: @Cody SO got its own app these days, good chance OP is using it, so it's off topic here and on topic in MSO.

Comment: @Shadow No, don't think so. Confirmed to be the "Stack Exchange" app in comments pre-migration. I [painstakingly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302224/undeleting-comments-breaks-the-layout) undeleted them on the original question.

Comment: @SurajRao many (most) users have no idea there is a difference or there are two separate apps.

Comment: Oh.. Where is my previous comment.. And what happening here???, am confused

Comment: @RameshRams your question was migrated from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ to https://meta.stackexchange.com since you confirmed the bug to be in StackExchange mobile app.. The older comments must have been deleted

Comment: @RameshRams there are two apps: Stack Overflow app and Stack Exchange app. You are using Stack Exchange app, so Meta Stack Exchange is where you should give feedback about it.

Comment: Anyway be continue with my question...   Thanks

Comment: You might want to add any other info like app version and platform

Comment: Also a new bug for i didn't get any notifications for movement for this question

Comment: Android phone am using

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/NqGAdK4.jpg